# Stop news from trying to put me in a political echo chamber?

Tags: voice-command, news-and-weather

I like to tell google to "play the news" for me during long road trips.  However, I noticed it's giving me news which has a clear lean towards one side of the political spectrum.  While I admittedly do lean slightly towards that side I want to hear unbiased news which makes strong arguments for both sides' political views so I can make well informed decisions, not sit in an an echo chamber that says one side is always right and I shouldn't bother considering the other side's views.

I've manually blocked the 3 major networks that have a clear political lean, and I'm trying to block other news providers when I hear reporting with a clear bias, but since I'm usually in the middle of a long drive when it happens I can't block the provider right then, and by the time I've stopped and could block someone I usually no longer know who it was I wanted to block.

Is there some easier way to keep google from trying to give me politically biased news other then trying to manually block every single biased news provider, which I suspect would take forever?  Failing that is there at least a way I can block the current news provider, if I've decided their reporting is too biased, via voice commands while driving?

Comment: you have funny expectations to google - the whole design is to keep you in a bubble

Comment: @alecks Sadly it is, and I understand why google would do it from a business perspective, but I hate it anyways.  American politics are going down hill because everyone is in their own bubble that tells them their side is perfect and the other side is evil people trying to destroy America, the net result is cooperation across parties becomes even worse then it already was and nothing gets done.  Of course Google is just one of dozens of tech companies helping people put themselves in a bubble so it's probably not fair to blame just them for it.

Comment: it's 2020. it's not just america. it's Aldous Huxley Brave New World, or Marc-Uwe Kling QualityLand. blame the consumers

Comment: By Google, do you mean [Google app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox)? Because otherwise, the question would become off-topic to us.

Comment: question is about voice-control - blocking news provider via voice commands